# Hasn't the WebComponent approach in Angular 2 an impact in performance?

Tags: http, angular, angular2-template, web-performance

Angular 2 replaced the controllers by web components and templates. All these files are requested from the server separately, aren't they? Isn't that an performance issue due to additional round trips (at least to fetch the template html)?

Comment: That's just for convenience during development. For production you'll bundle everything, I guess. I didn't look much into this yet, and ng2 is still in beta, but as it gets closer to release, tools will improve and more guides/tutorials will come...

Comment: Yup, you can make components lazy-loaded explicitely, but otherwise all will be loaded at once after build.

Comment: The big question here is if we bundle everything we'll break lazy loading of components since everything is transferred in one file. I am quite curious about how the Angular team reduces the amount of files being fetched from the server and still keep the lazy loading to work.

Comment: For sure, bundling is an option for JS files. But the templates can't be bundled and every component has to be fetched separately. Just wondering, how this shall lead to a performing solution.

Comment: @Mrk38 You can export templates as strings. I played with it for a bit, just wrap HTML with `export default var "<div class="component__container">....</div>"` (using ES6 backtick instead of quotes), import them and assign to components' `template` property. @osi As for bundling, you should bundle things that are related, big chunks of your app. For example you'll have one bundle for 'public' stuff then lazy-load 'private' section when user logs in... Doesn't make sense to load every route separately if they're 10K each (;